# How to construct SQL Server table from a text file

Tags: sql-server, text, import, row

I have a text file of containing data of type as shown here i.e.

```
$index 57320   
$title Efficient vector processing on dataflow supercomputer SIGMA-1  
$author K. Hiraki;S. Sekiguchi;T. Shimada  
$affiliation Electrotechnical Laboratory, Japan  
$time 1988  
$venue Proceedings of the 1988 ACM/IEEE conference on Supercomputing  
$citation 1022  
$abstract Efficiency in vector handling is the key to obtaining high...  

$index 57321   
$title Efficient vector processing on dataflow supercomputer SIGMA-1  
$author K. Hiraki;S. Sekiguchi;T. Shimada  
$affiliation Electrotechnical Laboratory, Japan  
$time 1988  
$venue Proceedings of the 1988 ACM/IEEE conference on Supercomputing  
$citation 1022  
$abstract Efficiency in vector handling is the key to obtaining high...  

$index 57322   
$title Efficient vector processing on dataflow supercomputer SIGMA-1  
$author K. Hiraki;S. Sekiguchi;T. Shimada  
$affiliation Electrotechnical Laboratory, Japan  
$time 1988  
$venue Proceedings of the 1988 ACM/IEEE conference on Supercomputing  
$citation 1022  
$abstract Efficiency in vector handling is the key to obtaining high...
```

Now I want to import all this data in SQL Server table whereas this text file contains `columns` as `#index`, `#title`, `#author`,...,`#abstract` and every `row break` have `empty line` in text file. The text file contains many number of rows which I have to import in SQL Server table.

Comment: @JesúsLópez Yeah I can write C# Code

Comment: @Taufel, then you need to parse the file and import it to SQL Server using INSERT statements or SqlBulkCopy class. Have you tried that? What problems do you have?. We are not going to write the code for you, instead we are helping if you get stuck.